# How can i obtain this data structure in NodeJS?

Tags: json, node.js, list, object, dictionary

I want to obtain the following structure and to be able to modify the user arrays of the appropriate key, and send it with a json response.

```
var data = ["A": [user1,user6,user9], "B": [user2], "E": [user3], "S": [user10], "Z": [user7], "J": [user8]]
```

`data` should be in this format when it is sent within a `jsonObject` to the client side (Swift): `[String : [User]]`

This is what i tried so far,

```
var dict = [];
var jsonObject = {};
User.find({}, function(err, users) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
        users.forEach(function(user) {
            dict[user.name.substring(0, 1)] = []
            dict[user.name.substring(0, 1)].push(user)
        });

    }
   jsonObject["key"] = dict
   return res.status(200).json(jsonObject);

});
```

Although `console.log(jsonObject)` prints it correctly, the json response is :

```
{
  "key": []
}
```

On The Client Side(Swift), i am trying to make something like this. But it gives errors.

```
.responseJSON(completionHandler: { response -> Void in
           if let jsonObj = response.result.value {
                 if let result = jsonObj["key"] as? [String: [User]]
                 {
                   var dict : [String: [User]] = result
                           print(dict)
                 } 
                                                 }
})
```

Any Help Please ?

Comment: Is `data` a object ` var data = {"A": [user1,user6,user9], "B": [user2], "E": [user3], "S": [user10], "Z": [user7], "J": [user8]}`

Comment: It is in this format on the ios side;   [String : [User]]

Answer (score 0):

I tried this approach. Seems to suffice your need of data.

```
var _ = require('lodash');

User.find({}, function (err, users) {
  if (err) {
    return res.status(500).send(err);
  }

  var data = {};
  _.each(users, (user) => {
    var key = user.name.substring(0, 1);
    var value = data[key];
    if (_.isUndefined(value)) {
        value = [];
    }
    value.push(user);
    data[key] = value;
  });

  return res.status(200).send({
    key: data
  });
});
```

I tested it with `var users = [{name: 'Andrew'}, {name: 'Blake'}, {name: Cathy'}, {name: 'Anderson'}, {name: 'Bresnan'}];`

Comment: Hello, your code gives me this : {"key": { "S": [{"name":"Sridhar"}]} but i need  something like this  {"key": [ "S": [{"name":"Sridhar"}] ] }, also, would you mind checking the updated question? i included my Swift codes